# Accessing a Gesture Recognizer Variable in Another Method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I have set up my gesture recognizer method here and for example I have set it to be disabled.

```
- (void)tapToAutoFocus:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

In anther method I would like to re-enable the gestureRecognizer like so:

```
-(void)anotherMethod
{
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

How do I go about accessing the gestureRecognizer variable in another method?  Sorry if this is basic, just not quite sure.  I tried setting the gestureRecognizer variable as a local one, however it messes up the tapToAutoFocus method.  Maybe I am just doing that part wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: You can create an iVar for that gesture so you can access to it anywhere in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

use instance variable. Declarate

```
{
UIGestureRecognizer *gesture;
}
```

in your *.h file.

in *tapToAutoFocus* method use

```
if([gestureRecognizer isKindOf:[UIGestureRecognizer class]]){
       gestureRecognizer.enabled=NO;
}
```

and then in other method

```
gesture.enabled=YES;
```